# How to get the ip address of the accepted in-bound socket?

Tags: c, sockets

My question is:

Server will create a socket, bind to a given port and with address = INADDR_ANY.

listen() & accept() the new connection. Then, we can get the client's ip-address

from accept().

Now, I want to know the ip-address of the Server, since the host of the server has

multiple NIC on it.

How to know the ip-address of the network interface with which the accepted in-bound socket is from?

I tried getsockname, it gave me the port number, but the ip is all-zero.

Update: Here is the code:

**Server.c (header files are removed)**

```
int main(void)
{

    struct sockaddr_in stSockAddr;
    int res, addr_len, SocketFD, ConnectFD;

    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    SocketFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(-1 == SocketFD)
    {
      perror("can not create socket");
      //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      return -1;
    }

    memset(&stSockAddr, 0, sizeof stSockAddr);
    stSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    stSockAddr.sin_port = htons(49335);
    stSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if(-1 == bind(SocketFD,(struct sockaddr *)&stSockAddr, sizeof stSockAddr))
    {
      perror("error bind failed");
      close(SocketFD);
     return -1;
    }


    printf("going to listen!\n"); 
    if(-1 == listen(SocketFD, 10))
    {   
      perror("error listen failed");
      close(SocketFD);
      //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      return -1; 
    }   

    ConnectFD = accept(SocketFD, NULL, NULL);

        if(0 > ConnectFD)
        {   
                perror("error accept failed");
                close(SocketFD);
                //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                return -1; 
        }   

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    res = getsockname (ConnectFD, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addr_len);
    // if you remove the following comment, that means, if you call 
    // two times of getsockname, the result will be correct.
    //res = getsockname (ConnectFD, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addr_len);

    printf("addr:%x\n", addr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    while(1) {
        if (getchar() == 'q')
                        break;
    }

    close(ConnectFD);
    close(SocketFD);
    return 0;
}
```

**Below is client.c:**

```
int main(void)
{

    struct sockaddr_in stSockAddr;

    int Res;

    int SocketFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (-1 == SocketFD)
    {
      perror("cannot create socket");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&stSockAddr, 0, sizeof stSockAddr);

    stSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    stSockAddr.sin_port = htons(49335);
    Res = inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.102", &stSockAddr.sin_addr);

    if (0 > Res)
    {
      perror("error: first parameter is not a valid address family");
      close(SocketFD);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (0 == Res)
    {
      perror("char string (second parameter does not contain valid ipaddress");
      close(SocketFD);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (-1 == connect(SocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&stSockAddr, sizeof stSockAddr))
    {
      perror("connect failed");
      close(SocketFD);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* perform read write operations ... */
    printf("client sockfd is successful\n"); 

      while(1) {

          if (getchar() == 'q')
              break;

      }


    shutdown(SocketFD, SHUT_RDWR);

    close(SocketFD);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please simply edit your question to provide more information. Answers are reserved strictly for solutions to your question. You can also use the comment feature under your question, or any answer to discuss a posted solution or provide clarification.

Answer (score 11):

Use `getsockname(2)` on the socket returned from `accept(2)`, *not* the socket returned from `bind(2)`.

Answer (score 8):

`getsockname()` gets name of passed socket.
in this example, you pass the socket which is created by
accept function in server.
this socket is in server side, so it's name & address is
related to server side.

if you want to know **"who was connected to me"**
you must use `getpeername()` instead of getsockname.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

> if you remove the following comment, that means, if you call 
>   two times of getsockname, the result will be correct.
>   res = getsockname (ConnectFD, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addr_len);

you must init addr_len.

```
    addr_len = sizeof(addr);
```